# An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'L:\'

Tags: angular

I see that this issue has come up repeatedly here on Stack Overflow. However, none of the other questions nor their answers seem to be on point.

I am doing a FormGroup/FormControl demo from an article [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/reactive-form-controls-form-groups-angular/#:%7E:text=In%20Angular%2C%20form%20controls%20are,that%20make%20up%20reactive%20forms.). I am doing it on a network G drive - the path for the repository is /g/employees/myName/Documents/articles-from-logrocket/Angular/ng-reactive . It is forked from the GitHub repo that goes with the article (in case that matters).

I ran an npm install and went through a few steps with the program and then did ng serve -o and got the following message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'L:\'
See "C:\Users\a161120\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-vM6S1X\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Here is what the log says:

```
[error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'L:\'
at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1845:7)
at toRealPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:390:13)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:24)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:917:27)
at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:113:19)
at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\Users\a161120\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:119:41)
at ServeCommandModule.getArchitectTargetOptions (C:\Users\a161120\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\architect-base-command-module.js:83:47)
at async ServeCommandModule.builder (C:\Users\a161120\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\architect-command-module.js:50:31)
at async runCommand (C:\Users\a161120\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-runner.js:113:5)
at async default_1 (C:\Users\a161120\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:70:16)
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. There is no L:\ drive on the network. I did a search in VS Code to see if an L drive was referenced anywhere, but I didn't find anything.